# ZSH always requires to restart terminal in order to access alias

Tags: macos, terminal, alias, zsh

I have added several aliases to my `.zshrc` file and they ONLY work if I restart terminal or use the `source ~/.zshrc` If I just open terminal, then type the alias, it will not recognize it, until I call `source ~/.zshrc`

So I know it's not a problem with the alias I created, I just have to load up the `.zshrc` file every time I want to use them.

What is going on? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't expect that you only have to edit a file and then, by magic, all your current zsh instances somehow ingest the changes, do you?

From the zsh man page, section *STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES* :

*if  the  shell  is  interactive,  commands are read from /etc/zshrc and then $ZDOTDIR/.zshrc*

($ZDOTDIR defaults to your $HOME). Hence, if you are in your terminal, you have three choices. Two of them you already found out (restart the terminal, source .zshrc manually). The third choice would be to just open a zsh subshell (by typing `zsh`).

Actually, there **is** a trick to do some "magic" in reading the file automatically: Zsh allows you to define a so-called *precmd hook*, which allows you to establish an arbitrary command to be executed just before a command prompt will be displayed. You could use it to source any file you like. If you want to use this feature, I strongly recommend **against** sourcing all of .zshrc. Sooner or later, you will have stuff in .zshrc that you don't want to be executed every time.

Instead, put your alias definitions into a separate file, say $HOME/.aliases, and in Zsh define the hook

```
function precmd {
  source $HOME/.aliases
}
```

If you later change the .aliases file, you would still have to type a Carriage Return in your shell, in order to provoke a new prompt to be written and the precmd to be executed, but this is less cumbersome than sourcing the file manually.